# How to check 6 RANDOM values out of 10 check boxes by using java script

Tags: javascript

(BY USING JAVASCRIPT)In my application I have multiple number of check boxes(suppose 10 boxes). When I am going to click a button like lucky dip, it has to select 6 random check boxes automatically. When I click same button for another time I want to get different 6 values from 10 initial values apart from first values.
I am able to checked 6 boxes(not different values) from 10 check boxes.

could you please give me some suggestions .

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: Confused as to what you mean by select 6 different check boxes and then when you click again you get another different 6 values... so is it supposed to be different from the first 6 you chose? If there are only 10 boxes total, wouldn't this be impossible?

Answer (score 1):

Here are steps you need to do, (using jQuery)

Step 1: Store the 10 `checkbox` id in an array.

Step 2: shuffle the array

Step 3: Loop the shuffled array using `for loop` till 6 values and `check` the checkbox

Here is the demo, http://jsfiddle.net/bcb8C/4/

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pure Javascript example that checks 6 random checkboxes:

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WLP3s/2/)**

```
function getRand(exclude, max)
{
    var dupe = true;
    var myRandom;

    while(dupe)
    {
        myRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * max);

        var found = false;
        for(var i=0;i<exclude.length; i++)
        {
            if(myRandom == exclude[i])
            {
                found = true;   
            }
        }

        if(!found) dupe = false;
    }

    return myRandom;
}

window.onload = function(){

    document.getElementById("lucky").onclick = function(){

        var checkboxList = document.getElementsByName("something[]");
        var rands = [];

        var total = 6;

        for(var j=0; j<checkboxList.length; j++){ checkboxList[j].checked = false; }

        for(var i=0; i<total; i++)
        {
            var myRandom = getRand(rands, checkboxList.length);
            rands.push(myRandom);
        }

        for(var x=0; x<rands.length; x++)
        {
            checkboxList[rands[x]].checked = true;   
        }

    };        

};​
```